# Is there a way that I can change the frequency of $interval dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I came up with this Typescript code to check connectivity.  It does a check every 60 seconds to confirm connectivity.  I would like to make it so that the connection checks are more frequent if the connection is lost.  Is there some way I could do this? I think it would mean changing the time interval but I am not sure how to do this once the $interval is started and running.

```
isConnected = (): ng.IPromise<any> => {
    return this.$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: self.ac.dataServer + '/api/Connect/Verify',
        ignoreLoadingBar: true
    } as ng.IRequestConfig);
};

openConnectionHandler = () => {
    var self = this;
    self.minutes = 0;
    self.mos.closeConnectionModal()
}

closeConnectionHandler = () => {
    var self = this;
    if (self.minutes == 0) {
        self.connectionModalBody = "Unable to establish a connection to the " + self.shortDomainName + " server";
    } else if (self.minutes == 1) {
        self.connectionModalBody = "Unable to establish a connection to the " + self.shortDomainName + " server for " + self.minutes + " minute.";
    } else {
        self.connectionModalBody = "Unable to establish a connection to the " + self.shortDomainName + " server for " + self.minutes + " minutes.";
    }
    self.minutes++;
    self.mos.openConnectionModal();
}

checkConnection = () => {
    var self = this;
    self.isConnected().then(self.openConnectionHandler, self.closeConnectionHandler);
    this.$interval(function () {
        self.isConnected().then(self.openConnectionHandler, self.closeConnectionHandler);
    }, 60 * 1000);
}
```

In my application controller I make this call when the application starts:

```
uss.checkConnection();
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: I believe you know that you can control the milliseconds as it is evident and clear for any one to see, do you want to make the calls quicker after a few executions when the connection is still not active?

Comment: Yes I would like to normally check every 60 seconds but then once the connection has failed I would like to check every 10 seconds until the connection works again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way. You cancel your current interval and create a new one with a different timeout value.

Example:

```
//here is where your interval initialization
var intervalPromise = $interval(intervalWhenConnectionIsUp, 60*1000);

function intervalWhenConnectionIsUp(){
    //your stuff goes here

    //let's say there is a variable which we can use to identify connection failures
    if(connectionFailed){
        //just cancel the current interval by the `cancel` method
        intervalPromise.cancel();

        //and set the proper interval function
        intervalPromise = $interval(intervalWhenNoConnection, 30*1000)
    }
}

function intervalWhenNoConnection(){
    //your stuff goes here

    if(connectionIsUp){
        //just cancel the current interval by the `cancel` method
        intervalPromise.cancel();

        //and set the proper interval function
        intervalPromise = $interval(intervalWhenConnectionIsUp, 60*1000)

    }
}
```

Comment: @lamisti - Thank you. I upvoted your answer.  Can you provide a solution that uses my code so that I and others could see how it would fit in. What I am not sure is how I should be calling the functions you have defined. Thank you

Comment: @Marilou I can try. A question: `self.isConnected()` returns a promise. If the connection is up, then the success handler will be called, otherwise the faield callback right?

Comment: @lamisti - Yes self.isConnected() does return a promise.  Actually it's just a $http call to the server to see if the client can connect to it.

Comment: @lamisti - I updated the question to show the isConnected.  Also when the connectivity is dropped I would like to check every 10 seconds instead of every 60.

Answer (score 1):

You can set-interval inside another function which takes a parameter as timeout for the $interval. And call this function with desired time interval.

Here is angularish code with no global variable

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $interval) {
  var intervalInstance;

  function onNoConnection() {
    checkConnectionAtRate(30*1000);
  }

  function checkConnectionAtRate(rate) {
      if (angular.isDefined(intervalInstance)) {
         $interval.cancel(intercalInstance);
      }
      intervalInstance = $interval(function() {
       //here goes the code;
       console.log('Something');
      }, rate);
  }

   function checkConnection() {
     checkConnectionAtRate(60 * 1000);
   }

}
```

UPDATE 2 to fit problem statement (not sure about typescript syntax)

```
  openConnectionHandler = () => {
      //same code
  }

  closeConnectionHandler = () => {
      //same code
      self.checkConnectionAt(30*1000);
  }

  checkConnection = () => {
      var self = this;
      self.checkConnectionAt(60 * 1000);
  }

  checkConnectionAt = (rate) => {
      var self = this;

      if(self.intervalInstance) {
          $interval.cancel(self.intervalInstance);
      }

      self.intervalInstance = $interval(function () {
          self.isConnected().then(self.openConnectionHandler, self.closeConnectionHandler);
      }, rate);
  }
```

Comment: don't like this solution. You create a global variable (intervalInstance), also you used `setInterval` instead of the angular $interval. There is a redundant check also, I don't like this solution.

Comment: You can create that instance within controller and not a global variable.

Comment: @Nils - I like your suggestion. To help myself and others, can you try to fit your answer around my code so it will help me to understand the way I can use it.  Thanks

Comment: @Nils - question was updated to show the isConnected() method.